# RBAC for raw requests

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

Trying to figure out how to set up RBAC to read from the custom metrics API. Here's the context...

I've got a service that is exposing custom metrics to Kubernetes. These are available through the following endpoint

```
/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/{ns}/services/{svc}/{metric}
```

The endpoint works and it's not the issue.

I have another service which role is to retrieve those metrics and act upon them. This is working properly on a local machine where permissions aren't a problem, but when deployed it's not and that's the issue here.

To remove suspicion... the deployment does have a `ServiceAccount`, with a `ClusterRole` and a `ClusterRoleBinding`.

So... here's what my `ClusterRole` looks so far (I'm sure there are already unnecessary things in there)

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: the-thing
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - apps
    resources:
      - deployments
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - patch
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - endpoints
      - namespaces
      - nodes
      - pods
      - services
    verbs: 
      - get
      - list
  - apiGroups:
      - custom.metrics.k8s.io
    resources:
      - "*"
    verbs:
      - "*"
```

I thought that it would come down to `custom.metrics.k8s.io` group, but apparently not...

If someone has any suggestions, help is much appreciated!

Comment: More details from the response: "services.custom.metrics.k8s.io hello-app is forbidden: User system:anonymous cannot get resource services/thingy_metric in API group custom.metrics.k8s.io in the namespace default".
The anonymous user doesn't look right... Going to investigate further...

Answer (score 1):

Ok... answering my own question here...

I was testing the service account to see if I missed something, but it seems that it had indeed permissions for what I wanted. I checked that with `can-i` tool.

```bash
$ kubectl auth can-i get custom_metric_name --as=system:serviceaccount:my-namespace:my-service-account
yes
```

So this pointed out to something on the request itself, since I already confirmed the container was using the correct service account.

More context: I'm using the [dotnet client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp) for this. And to retrieve the metrics, one must use the generic `HttpClient` from the `Kubernetes` instance.

```cs
Kubernetes client = ...;

HttpClient httpClient = client.HttpClient;
```

Locally this works, because no credentials are required, but inside the cluster, the [credentials have to be set](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/blob/2959174eb6e8ba85bdf4a17ea65e4c36ec84cd87/src/KubernetesClient/Kubernetes.cs#L149) in the `HttpRequestMessage` before being processed and this part was missing.

Because I am using the `HttpClient` directly, I was not setting the credentials before doing the request. In fact, I as calling `GetAsync` directly instead of constructing the request message. After setting the credentials, the request works.

```cs
var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage( HttpMethod.Get, url );

if ( client.Credentials != null )
{
    await client.Credentials.ProcessHttpRequestAsync( httpRequest, cancellationToken );
}
```

Hope this helps someone...